# How to build a single sign-on application (email and pass)?

Tags: angular, single-sign-on

I want to build a single login interface (with Angular) which should be a kind of stand alone, so that it can be used and embedded from/on any page.

E.g. a customer can embed it on his index page as over layer and the code/functions should be will passed from a JavaScript API and build the the UI and the connection.

I'am thinking about a concept like single sign-on application which allows users to interact on other websites through their account on Facebook. 
Something like Facebook connect.

What's the best approach to reach this? Preferred technology is Angular2, Angular4

Comment: Many of the single sign-on mechanisms you reference use OAuth2. It's a bit of a pain to implement yourself, so I'd recommend finding a library that does it already

Comment: I do have already a login app (mail and pass) with angular and it's using JWT Auth - sending credentials to server and getting token in response. The point is how can I provide it as a single sign-on, so that it can be embedded by a customer e.g.
In other words, how to provide it to the customer... as a link which is not what I want and won't make sense for me... I'am thinking about a kind of script added in the head `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` and a scriptlet (javascript function) which can be embedded invoked and uses the API. Would that be a correct scenario?

Comment: I understand but it's not that simple. Sure, you can have a 3rd party app (3PA) pass through credentials (over SSL?) and then relay the auth token. Now the 3PA can impersonate your user and you won't know the difference. A compromised 3PA = all users are vulnerable. You're intentionally creating a man-in-the-middle situation. That's why OAuth and other protocols exist to avoid these problems. In that scenario, the 3PA sets up the communication but the user's browser talks straight to your server to authenticate, then a token is delegated to the 3P. That way, nobody else can steal user creds.

Comment: What about if I do have a microservice (API interface) between, which I talk to and it connect to customer Server/DataBase and pass me the response etc.? e.g. Forgerock?

Comment: I'm not sure what adding another layer (generic API) adds to the architecture. using a proper IAM solution will be a massive improvement, but it all comes down to how you're authenticating to the IAM, and what you do with the auth token afterwards. There are literally hundreds of ways to solve this problem, and they all have benefits/costs. Honestly, your first step should be to take a step back and do some proper risk/architecture analysis. Who are you defending against, what are their capabilities, how much hassle are you willing to accept in exchange for security, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks. All the steps regarding analysis, architecture etc. have been done or in progress. And the costs for FR etc. are included when it will be in use.
Going back to your first comment... to be honest, I don't know if there is any library or Plugins providing such built-in solution for single sign-on/in. Or do I misunderstood what you meant. Correct me if the case please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not entirely an answer but too long for a comment]

I think the fundamental mis-match is that you're asking "how do I do auth" and I'm countering with "there are lots of ways, with varied costs/benefits. You need to assess them and pick the right approach for your use case. OAuth2 is a sensible starting point, but many others exist."

After that, finding a library that does the work is (relatively) simple.

So... there are a number of things which I think you'll need to get nailed down before you can proceed.

My initial questions would be:

- What level of security do we need to offer end-users considering the data that's being exposed.
- Who are our adversaries? Hackers? Nation States? How about disgruntled employees?
- How are we going to mitigate against all of the above?
- What logging and auditing will be needed so that after a breach we can understand what happened.
- If we're using a 3rd party IAM service, what data does it expect to be passed to it and what does it return. Does it handle a 3-way auth (us, end-user, third party) automatically or is that something that has to be built around it? If the latter, does the IAM provider have an SDK/similar that includes the functionality we need.

Broad strokes, I'd suggest an architecture that does *something like* this:

- User wants to authenticate in third party app
- 3rd party redirects the user to your server/api/IAM platform where the user logs in (or reclaims an active session).
- Your system prompts the user to allow the 3PA access to (a subset of?) your data.
- Assuming the user approves, redirect the user back to the 3PA, along with an auth token *specific to that 3PA*.

The 3PA can then use that token to act on behalf of the user until the token is cancelled.

Benefits:

- 3PA never sees user credentials, only learns of its token after a successful approval.
- Tokens are specific per-service, meaning you can revoke permission for one site without revoking for all.
- User can track who has authorised access to their details.
- You can track which systems are authenticating to you (depending on how much info you ask for on the initial connect, and whether 3PA have to pre-register and get an ID to be able to request authentication).

What I've described is basically, a minimalist OAuth workflow. You could go about implementing it yourself, but there are a lot of pitfalls and I'm not convinced you fully appreciate the security implications of what you're attempting, so I'd definitely suggest using a known-good process rather than trying to roll your own.

Assuming OAuth fits your use-case.... I've never had to do this from Angular so can't recommend a library but a quick Google shows dozens... Near the top of the results was a simple tutorial: https://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/tutorials/how-to-implement-safe-signin-via-oauth

And one potential library: https://github.com/oauthjs/angular-oauth2 (although at a glance, that doesn't seem to handle the intercepted-credentials scenario very well)